# Require another file before require file functions.php Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Same as title, i want require  file 'foo.php' before wordpress require 'functions.php' in theme. What's solution? Somebody can help me?

Comment: I know it doesn't answer the question...but why do you need to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Child Theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes).

Basically you just do this:

> Create a directory in your themes directory to hold the child theme.
>   The theme directory is wp-content/themes. You should name the
>   directory without any space as part of the name, and it is common
>   practice to use the name of the parent theme folder with “-child”
>   appended to it. For example, if you are making a child of the
>   twentyfourteen theme, your folder name would be twentyfourteen-child.

Inside, you can create a functions.php and add the code you want, you can even call other files, like your foo.php:

> (...) the functions.php of a child theme does not override its counterpart
>   from the parent. Instead, it is loaded in addition to the parent’s
>   functions.php. (Specifically, it is loaded right before the parent’s
>   file.)

You can also create a plugin, they are loaded before functions.php, you can take a look at the loading order here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26537/between-functions-php-widgets-and-plugins-which-is-loaded-first